# Please don't migrate game recommendations to Gaming

Tags: discussion, migration, gaming

Hi Super Users! I'm [Grace Note](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/85/grace-note) from [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), here to make a polite request.

A finalized ruling has been made. While I don't know if you even got any during the decision period after my request, I nevertheless thank everyone here for listening and respecting my earlier request (which you may re-read in the [revision history](https://meta.superuser.com/posts/1746/revisions)).

Our official policy on Gaming is **No Game Recommendations**. So, keeping in tune with the previous request, I'd like to expand my request's formerly temporary nature to the following: **please do not migrate game recommendations to Gaming**. Now, instead of being to avoid confusion, it's because those questions no longer belong on the site and would be closed post-migration - an act that still poses no point. If you encounter any from this point forward, I ask that you please simply close them as off-topic here.

Comment: I presume this question is triggered by the migration of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/219696/funny-christmas-game-for-ten-year-olds-kid-closed) question? I think I voted to just close it, but obviously these things work on a majority (or moderator override, obviously). I think you may find you have an underlying problem here - meta.SU doesn't feel particularly active so I imagine many 3k SU users won't see this post, and any of those non-meta-reading 3k SU users that *don't* use gaming won't even know there is a problem...

Comment: @DMA That was the trigger point, aye, but I lacked the capacity to post a comment (as it is locked). I can accept there being a lack of visibility to this request, but my hope is that those who do read this can inform users who didn't, should this come up again. Some word is better than no word, and I like to be proactive even if it isn't even a real problem yet. I also don't blame anyone if they do get migrated (I just hope to reduce its frequency); Super User has good reason to disallow Gaming, and we have your own Ivo Flipse to thank for helping us understand a lot about your site.

Comment: What if we just edit the post to be more like "identify this game" type posts which last heard are for some reason welcome?

Comment: @random Then we'll start picketing on your lawn. But in seriosity, there is enough difference between the nature of an identification question (seeking 1 answer) and a recommendation question (seeking all applicable answers), and we are already imposing increased scrutiny on identification questions. A recommendation that can pass off as an identification is going to be overly vague and broad by the standards that identification should be judged on.

Answer (score 12):

I'm heavily involved in the discussion over at Gaming and will keep you guys posted.

For now I would even go as far as to halt any migrations to Gaming for now until they figure out their own policies.

Yes @Diago, I'm looking at you ;-) We can always migrate the questions over at a later point in time, but we don't want to do to Gaming what SO is doing to us!